# Subset all levels of a single factor

Tags: r

Is there a way to subset all levels of a single factor in one clean swoop?

Case: Assuming you have a data frame where one of the columns is a factor (data$factor) and you want to create subset data frames that contain only one level of the factor.  This is simple to do when there are a small number of factors by writing separate subset commands.  However, what if you have a large number of levels (e.g. 50+ levels)?  Is there a command or a clever way to create all the subsets in such a case without having to write 50+ subset commands?

Comment: @HongOoi Just tried it out--that looks to do the trick. However, the groups/subsets all go into one variable (for example, subsets<-split(df, data$factor, drop=FALSE).  How does one access each of the subsets within the single variable "subsets"?

Comment: @HongOoi Nevermind! Figured it out. Thanks for your help!! In case, anyone is interested, the groups can be accessed from subsets, e.g. group1<-subsets[[1]], group2<-subsets[[2]], etc.

Comment: @whistler, you can post your findings as an answer and ***accept*** it. It would make it much easier for someone else with a similar problem to find a solved answer instead of reading through comments to a question (which is usually meant for clarifications and related discussion).

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments and help. I posted my findings as an answer, but stackoverflow will not allow me to accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without having to create a loop, the SPLIT function is key to solving this problem.

Assuming the factor column you want to subset (or subgroup) is in the column "factor" of the data frame "data" do:

```
subsets<-split(data, data$factor, drop=TRUE)
```

This will create a list of subsets based on the factor value. The list will have the same length as the number of factors.

If you need to put each subset in a separate data frame, you can access them by doing the following:

```
group1<-subsets[[1]]
group2<-subsets[[2]]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop over the requested factor values as follows:

```
vals <- sort (unique (data[[factor]]))
for (i in 1:length(vals)) {
   subset <- (data[[factor]]==vals[i])
   n <- length (data[[factor]][(subset)])
   if (n >= min.n) {
      ...
   }
}
```