# Dataset sub-setting based on a factor variable that generates as many subsets as the factor length

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm working on a dataset (named "scores") that contains only numerical variables but also one factor that indicates the country that the numerical is from. All those are columns in one dataset.

I'm puzzled with making the part of the code that I use for subsetting more independent. For example, in the dataset "scores" I use the following to generate a subset for each country:

```
scores_us <- scores[which(scores$Country== 1)]
scores_uk <- scores[which(scores$Country== 2)]
scores_it <- scores[which(scores$Country== 3)]
```

What I need to do is to make this part more independent so when someone who isn't familiar with R runs it for a different group of countries, to not always have to write one line for each level of the factor.

Perhaps a loop that goes through the factor and just creates as many subsets as its levels?

Thank you very much in advance, for any ideas.

P.s I tried using `for i in length(scores$Country)` but it returns one subset with all the countries together instead of three.

Updated question:

You're right, I've been quite unclear. My dataset is on scores 1-10 (opinion/ perception) that represent ordinal data for a group of countries. My next step is to calculate the "NPS- Net Promoter Score" for each country for all the columns. So far, I subset each country, and then, I apply the nps function (nps package) on each, which results to a new list that contains the NPS number of each question (the scores columns). A sample of the code for doing that is:

```
scores_us <- scores[which(scores$Country== 1)]
scores_uk <- scores[which(scores$Country== 2)]
scores_it <- scores[which(scores$Country== 3)]          

nps_us<-round(sapply(scores_us, nps)*100)
nps_uk<-round(sapply(scores_uk, nps)*100) 
nps_it<-round(sapply(scores_it, nps)*100)
```

The `split` method that you propose, achieves to subset without the user having to write one line of code for each country. It generates a list of dataframes. However, when using sapply/lapply to calculate the nps it returns the warning: Data of class data.frame supplied; converted to numeric and the elements are NAs.

Perhaps because the output lists have different dimensions than the listed dataframes (lst1)? Or because nps doesn't work with the apply family?

Your alternative to group_by and then do the nps function returns the nps result 
 but without doing each country's. This is what I used for that: `scores_df %>% group_by(Country) %>% lapply(., nps)`.

If there was a way for the `nps` to work on the list of dataframes that the `split` generates would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split` to split into a `list` of `data.frame`s (assuming that 'scores_df' and 'scores' have the same dimensions)

```
lst1 <- split(scores_df, scores$Country)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  yes scores_df and scores are the same dataset. It was a typo! Already edited my post to avoid confusion. I'll try this.

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, now if I want to use the subsets generated by the split I guess I need to do what it is proposed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905463/subset-all-levels-of-a-single-factor . Right? In this case, again I can't avoid writing a line of code for each level of the "Country" factor. Perhaps, it's impossible what I'm trying to do. For example, now if I try to apply a function on "lst1" it ends with error.

Comment: @Y.Ch  It is not clear about your ultimate objective.  If it is to do some calculations on other columns by 'Country',  it can be done with a groupby operation.  i.e. `scores_df %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(Valmean = mean(col))` otherwise, to work on `list`s, use `lapply/sapply` i.e. `lapply(lst1, function(x) mean(x$Col))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and it's true that it wasn't very clear. I have updated the initial post responding to your comment because here it would be a long comment. If you have the time check the update. Cheers.

Comment: @Y.Ch I think you need `lapply(lst1, function(x) round(sapply(x, nps)*100))`

Comment: damn you made it work. Thanks for this answer, other people have posted similar problems on stackoverflow but I bet this is the first complete answer. Thanks again!